# Connecting the Markers on the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have applications that marks markers on the map,  i trying write code about the function that connects all the points and I do not know how to do it.
On the stack I can not find a similar topic (android). 
Are there any guides?
Any help will be useful, because I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line on the map with the points of your markers.  Make a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) and add it to the map.